ghost script gives error on pdf file containing % in file name
I have problems with ghostscript when the name of the file to be converted contains %.
The following script fails with the error message **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
/opt/ghostscript-10.02.0/bin/gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r300 -sOutputFile="/tmp/of2phoenix/1734088654367/OF8P_2412_0498/001_Payment Confirmation%.pdf_conv" -c "<< /Install { { 0.60 gt { 1 } { 0 } ifelse } settransfer } >> setpagedevice" -- "/tmp/of2phoenix/1734088654367/OF8P_2412_0498/001_Payment Confirmation%.pdf"


https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=688563 <- "the string argument should have
%% for each instance of % desired in the output file name"
